# how to solve Session already invalidated in jboss 6.4

Tags: hibernate, session, session-state, jboss6.x

Getting session invalidated on browser console, I am using jboss 6.4, hibernate 3.

> JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000066: Exception report JBWEB000068: message
>   JBWEB000212: Session already invalidated JBWEB000069: description
>   JBWEB000145: The server encountered an internal error that prevented
>   it from fulfilling this request. JBWEB000070: exception
>
> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB000212: Session already invalidated
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.getAttribute(StandardSession.java:1013)
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.getAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:110)
>   org.apache.jsp.InstitutionLoginHome_jsp._jspService(InstitutionLoginHome_jsp.java:247)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:246)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   com.scm.filter.RequestLoggingFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggingFilter.java:59)
> ```